# Sellenium/BrowserMob won't connect to HTTPS port

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im writing an automated flow using Selenium and Java and I need to
connect via an authenticated HTTPS proxy using a "< username> " and "< password >".
Since Selenium doesn't support proxy authentication  I'm using the standard technique of
running BrowserMobProxyServer and "chaining" the external proxy to it. While the code below works great with regular HTTP
For some reason it doesn't work with HTTPS and Im getting ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED in my browser.

note that
`"curl -v -x https://<username>:<password>@<proxy hostname>:<proxy HTTPS port> https://ipinfo.io"`
works perfectly fine one my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,
So I suspect that it is code error.

```
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.5.0'
implementation 'net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.5'

public static BrowserMobProxyServer createLocalProxy(String hostname, String port,
                                                     String username, String password) {
    BrowserMobProxyServer proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();

    // Handling http and https URLs
    proxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
    // // remote proxy as added to the chain of locally running proxy server
    proxy.setChainedProxy(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, Integer.parseInt(port)));
    proxy.chainedProxyAuthorization(username, password, AuthType.BASIC);
    proxy.setMitmManager(ImpersonatingMitmManager.builder().trustAllServers(true).build());

    // This is a local proxy in JVM. Port is assigned automatically.
    // It must be stopped using the stop() method before exiting.
    proxy.start(0);
    return proxy;
}
// proxy setup
BrowserMobProxy proxy =
        createLocalProxy("<proxy hostname>", "<proxy HTTPS port>", "<user name>",
                "<password>");

Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:" + proxy.getPort());
seleniumProxy.setSslProxy("localhost:" + proxy.getPort());
<some additional options here>
options.setProxy(seleniumProxy);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to override ChainedProxyManager instead of using MitmManager. I had encountered a similar problem and MitmManager did not help me. For instance,

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
String credentials = BrowserMobHttpUtil.base64EncodeBasicCredentials(username, password);

BrowserMobProxyServer browserMobProxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
browserMobProxy.setChainedProxyManager(new SSLSupportChainedProxyManager(address, credentials));
browserMobProxy.start();


@RequiredArgsConstructor
private static class SSLSupportChainedProxyManager implements ChainedProxyManager {

    private final SelfSignedSslEngineSource selfSignedSslEngineSource = new SelfSignedSslEngineSource(true);

    private final InetSocketAddress upstreamProxyAddress;
    private final String credentials;

    @Override
    public void lookupChainedProxies(HttpRequest httpRequest, Queue<ChainedProxy> chainedProxies) {

        chainedProxies.add(new ChainedProxyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public InetSocketAddress getChainedProxyAddress() {
                return upstreamProxyAddress;
            }

            @Override
            public void filterRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
                if (httpObject instanceof HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                    httpRequest.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.PROXY_AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + credentials);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean requiresEncryption() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public SSLEngine newSslEngine() {
                return selfSignedSslEngineSource.newSslEngine();
            }

            @Override
            public SSLEngine newSslEngine(String peerHost, int peerPort) {
                return selfSignedSslEngineSource.newSslEngine(peerHost, peerPort);
            }
        });
    }
}
```